# Cardview loses its radius when taken a screenshot programmatically

Tags: bitmap, android-canvas, android-constraintlayout, android-cardview

I have constraintlayout within cardview. The cardview looks fine on the screen. It is only when taken a screenshot,it is rendered to a bitmap thats when it loses the corners. I have added the picture of the bitmap view. The constraintlayout overlaps the rounded corners. I need edge to edge roundness.

Below is the screenshot of the emulator showing round corners correctly:

[image: Below is the image of the cardview within a Constraintlayout]

Here is the view rendered to a bitmap:

[image: Here is the view rendered to a bitmap.]

Below is my sample code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CardView cardView;
    private Button button;
    private ConstraintLayout parentLayoutA;
    private ConstraintLayout layoutB;
    private ConstraintLayout childLayout;
    private ConstraintSet innerSet;
    private ConstraintSet outerSet;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        CreateCardViewProgrammatically();
    }


    public void CreateCardViewProgrammatically(){

        cardView = new CardView(this);
        childLayout = new ConstraintLayout(this);
        parentLayoutA = new ConstraintLayout(this);
        layoutB = new ConstraintLayout(this);
        button = new Button(this);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            layoutB.setClipToOutline(true);
        }

        cardView.setRadius(150);

        button.setText("Click!!");
        button.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               takeScreenShot();
            }
        });

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            parentLayoutA.setId(View.generateViewId());
            layoutB.setId(View.generateViewId());
            childLayout.setId(View.generateViewId());
            cardView.setId(View.generateViewId());
            button.setId(View.generateViewId());
        }

        innerSet = new ConstraintSet();
        outerSet = new ConstraintSet();

        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams parentParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );

        layoutB.setLayoutParams(parentParams);
        childLayout.setLayoutParams(parentParams);
        cardView.setCardElevation(0);
        cardView.setPadding(50,50,50,50);

        parentLayoutA.addView(layoutB);
        layoutB.addView(cardView);
        cardView.addView(childLayout);
        childLayout.addView(button);

        innerSet.centerHorizontally(button.getId(), ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID);
        innerSet.centerVertically(button.getId(), ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID);
        innerSet.constrainHeight(button.getId(), 200);

        outerSet.connect(cardView.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END, 200);
        outerSet.connect(cardView.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, 200);
        outerSet.centerHorizontally(cardView.getId(), ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID);
        outerSet.centerVertically(cardView.getId(), ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID);
        outerSet.constrainHeight(cardView.getId(), 1500);

        innerSet.applyTo(childLayout);
        outerSet.applyTo(layoutB);

        setContentView(parentLayoutA);

        parentLayoutA.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        layoutB.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        childLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    public void takeScreenShot() {
        imageFromView(parentLayoutA);
    }

    public Bitmap imageFromView(View view) {

        DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getApplication().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = view.getWidth() > 0 ? view.getWidth() : metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = view.getHeight() > 0 ? view.getHeight() : metrics.heightPixels;

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);

        return bitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at your code, I am not clear on what you are trying to accomplish. However, if you change the following line

```
cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

to

```
cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

and delete the line

```
childLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

you will see your screen image captured the way I think you want.

---

The underlying problem is that the rounded corner clipping is dependent upon the hardware layer which is enabled for the canvas generated by the view display system but is turned off when you generate your own bitmap and canvas. You can check this with [Canvas#isHardwareAccelerated()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#isHardwareAccelerated()),

Take a look at [Taking Screenshot Programmatically Using PixelCopy Api](https://medium.com/@shiveshmehta09/taking-screenshot-programmatically-using-pixelcopy-api-83c84643b02a) for an approach that you might be able to take. Also, see [PixelCopy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy).

[Here](https://github.com/Cheticamp/TakeScreenshot) is a small project on GitHub demonstrating how to go about capturing a layout. This demo app simply uses the code in the question to display a layout, captures the layout and redisplays it in an *ImageView*. A *TextView* in the redisplay simply displays "Captured!"

[image]

Comment: The purpose of the sample code is to show when a cardview is inside a constraintlayout A and another constraintlayout B is inside the cardview, the round corners are gone when you take a screenshot of A. The purpose of the colors is just to show the problem.

Comment: @SupreetKaur so this solves the problem? Or still corners are gone? You have selected it as a correct answer

Comment: I just tested and it works for api 28. But it does not work below api 28. I see in your code that you left `Bitmap.createBitmap` as it is for api 28. OP still reoccures, i.e. corners are gone

Comment: The accepted answer only worked for versions higher than O. For lower API versions, we had to clip the corners of the canvas using canvas.clipPath after subclassing the view and overriding the ondraw method.That’s the only way we were able to solve the problem.